# self.context.delete is not a function in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap for modal, Im trying to delete a record from a table, I have a `DeletemodalComponent` and an `EmployeeComponent`.

**DeletemodlalComponent**

```
import {Component,OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons, NgbModalRef, NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deletemodal',
  templateUrl: './deletemodal.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deletemodal.component.css']
})
export class DeletemodalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name;
  closeResult:string; 
  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //const modalRef = this.modalService.open(DeletemodalComponent);
  }
}
```

**EmployeeComponent**

```
import { Component,Inject, OnInit,AfterViewInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons, NgbModalRef, NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DeletemodalComponent } from 'app/deletemodal/deletemodal.component';
import { EmployeeService } from 'app/services/employee.service';
import { Employee} from "app/services/employee";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css'],
})

export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  public datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  employees: Employee[] = [];
  errMesg: any; 
  public emp_data:any;
  closeResult: string;
  public markersData: any;
  name:string;
  id:number;
  modalTitle:string;
  modalRef: NgbModalRef;

  constructor(@Inject(Http)
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private http:Http,
    private employeeservice:EmployeeService,
    private modalService: NgbModal
    //private modal: NgbModal,
    ) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
       this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5
    };
    this.getEmployees();
  }

  /* Options for Modal */
  modalOptions : NgbModalOptions = {
    size:'lg'
  };

  getEmployees(){
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        employees => {
        this.employees = employees;
        this.dtTrigger.next();
         console.log(employees);
      });
  }
   rerender(): void {
    this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.destroy();
      this.employees;
    });
  }

delete(id) {
    console.log(id); 
    //delete employee code
  }

  open(content,employee) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(DeletemodalComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.id = employee.id;
  }
  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

I have imported `DeletemodalComponent` in `EmployeeComponent`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="delete(id)">Delete</button>
```

This line is in `deletemodal.html` and calls delete function in `EmployeeComponent`. I think `DeletemodalComponent` don't have `delete()` and that's why it is giving this error, is there a way to call `delete()` of `EmployeeComponent` from `DeletemodalComponent`'s template ?

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to have `delete` method in `DeletemodalComponent`

Comment: @yurzui So, I need to do delete employee operation in `DeletemodalComponent` ?

Comment: You can emit event by using @Output

Comment: @yurzui I don't have much idea about emitting event and `@Output`, but let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by yurzui, use `@Output`. I would also slightly change `delete` to `deleteEmployee` instead. So, in your modal component, add the following:

```
@Output() deleteEmployee = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

and the click event would be where you pass the id:

```
(click)="deleteEmployee.emit(id)"
```

and in your parent `EmployeeComponent`, in the child tag add the following:

```
<app-deletemodal (deleteEmployee)="deleteEmployee($event)"></app-deletemodal>
```

Now in `deleteEmployee` you have the id:

```
deleteEmployee(id) {
  console.log(id) // id here now in parent comp
}
```

More about `@Output` and other ways to interact from the **[official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)**.